# Parallel.ForEach not working, while normal For Each loop is

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multithreading, lambda, parallel-processing

The title is pretty self explanatory. I have a bit of code that works when the code is executed sequentially and doesn't if I use `Parallel` loops. I call it by using

```
RunXTransposingThreads(Arr1, Arr2, Arr3, Arr4)
```

Being `Arr`s `Dim Arr1(,) As Single = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Single), 1025, 129)`

```
Sub RunXTransposingThreads(ParamArray ArraysToTranspose() As Array)

    Parallel.ForEach(Of Array)(ArraysToTranspose,
        Sub(inArray)
            Dim x As Integer = CInt(inArray.GetLength(1))
            Dim y As Integer = CInt(inArray.GetLength(0))
            Dim outArray(,) As Single = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Single), x, y)
            For i As Integer = 0 To x - 1
                For j As Integer = 0 To y - 1
                    outArray(i, j) = inArray(j, i)
                Next
            Next
            inArray = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Single), x, y)
            Array.Copy(outArray, inArray, inArray.Length)
        End Sub)
```

I tried it to use `Function` a instead of a `Sub`, but nothing worked. All the elements in the `ArrayToTranspose()` `Array` are not transposed in the main subroutine, which means that `Arr1` before `RunXTransposingThreads` is the same as after that line.

If I use a normal `For Each` cycle though, all works perfectly.

Comment: The delegate to be executed for each item by the `Parallel.ForEach` method is an `Action`, not a `Func`.  That means the method that that delegate refers to is supposed to be a `Sub`, not a `Function`. You're using a `Function`. What exactly do you expect to happen to the object you return from that `Function`?  Where do you think it is supposed to go? In fact, it is simply ignored, because it gets executed via an `Action` delegate, which doesn't return anything.

Comment: Please read the last paragraph: I tried to use a Sub too, but it wouldn't work anyway. I've seen examples using functions too, that's why I tried. Edited the code anyway, so it's more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to return an array of arrays from a Parallel loop, creating local copies to transpose in some nested [Parallel.For](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783539(v=vs.110).aspx) loops and returning makes more sense to me.

In the end you do already by using For loops not For Each's.

```
Private Function RunXTransposingThreadsParallel(ParamArray ArraysToTranspose() As Array) As Array
    Dim transposedOnes(arraysToTranspose.Length - 1) As Array

    Parallel.For(0, arraysToTranspose.Length, Sub(i) ' Loop #1
        Dim x = arraysToTranspose(i).GetLength(0)
        Dim y = arraysToTranspose(i).GetLength(1)
        transposedOnes(i) = New Single(y - 1, x - 1){}
        Parallel.For(0, x, Sub(xl) ' Loop #2
            Parallel.For(0, y, Sub(yl) ' Loop #3
                transposedOnes(i)(yl, xl) = arraysToTranspose(i)(xl, yl)
            End Sub)
        End Sub)
    End Sub)

    Return transposedOnes
End Function

' Usage
' Dim result = RunXTransposingThreadsParallel(Arr1, Arr2, Arr3, Arr4)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to get rid of the line:

```
inArray = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(Single), x, y)
```

It is overwriting the local reference `inArray` (passed in as an argument) and causing the new value to not make it out of the anonymous method block. `inArray` is already created, reusing the instance isn't a problem, and allows the modified array to make it out of the method.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped me to understand! I have another problem in this case, though. If I get rid of that line, I cannot resize `inArray` which ultimately maintains its dimensions (y,x). How can I make it (x,y)?

Comment: I don't think that is going to be possible.  The arguments of `Action` are not defined as `out` parameters, so changing the reference inside the `Action` will never propagate back to the original call.

Comment: The problem with modifying the "shape" of the array is coming from the `ParamArray`.  I might have a solution. Give me a few minutes to make sure it works.

Comment: Sorry, I got pulled away for something at work.  I'm not going to have time to look at this for a while.

Comment: every help is appreciated (besides, I just found out that `Array`s are not thread-safe and I don't really know anymore what to do...)

Comment: Check System.Collections.Concurrent Namespace for thread safe collections.